# asp.net mvc custom template for application forms and page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, templates

everyone, I'm really new with asp.net mvc

I have given this new task that converting existing application using asp.net webform into asp.net mvc

This application have basically have 3 type template form:

1. Grid Template (include the navigation such paging and search, and input/view form/panel shown after click, can be below or hide the grid)
2. Process Template (Grid with check box on each item to process)
3. Non-Grid Template (just input form, usually used for application parameter form)

This application also has some template pages, but basically this template page is combining just 1 template form or more (can be same template form), e.g parameter application form or sales order application (master and detail). The page can also has many detail show in tabs.

How do I achieve this templates using asp.net mvc as efficient as possible rather than just create new form and copy-paste from the other form. 
I mean to minimalize the same code I have to write rather the specific thing that differentiate the form purpose, e.g the code just show the input form after click item.

Can anyone show me how I can do it or solution that came near to what I need? 
Any link to tutorial, step by step, or anything?

Or if there any reasons I can't/shouldn't do it with asp.net mvc and what is the best way?

Thanks in advance and sorry if there are any mistakes in my words.

Answer (score 1):

**Editor/Display templates**
They are mostly used for edit/display forms such as editing/displaying user profile data form, etc.  Kind of like your Non-Grid Template. You can create Object templates, place them in the corresponding folders of the solution and they will be automatically every time you render your model via Html.EditorForModel() or Html.DisplayForModel helpers. Here is a good article to start with [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 4: Custom Object Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html)

**Shared views**
I'm not sure what your Process template looks like but it seems it's a fixed number column grid like a one column with chackboxes and one more column with names of the items to process. In this case you'd better create an interface and a shared view. Then you can use the interface to map your view model to and render it with your shared view via Html.Partial helper.

**Html helpers**
For more advance grid templates just use a grid template, there are a lot of online, personelly I prefer Grid helper from MvcContrib library.

Two combine different templates within a single page use layout, sections and again shared view. Here is a good video about how to create and use them [Asp Net MVC 4 - 02 Creating Layout, Views and Partial Views](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYOCMuarEW8)

Can't advice anything more specific as I don't really know what you WebForm application actually looks like but I think I described everything you need to start with.

Hope it helps!